# Dynamically instancing a class then deleting it right away?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I created my own class but when I try to instantiate it I run into a wall.

Here's my code:

```
m_interpolation = new Interpolation(m_mesureList, width, height, parent);
delete m_interpolation;
```

Which generates the error:

> Heap block at 0B3E9E40 modified at 0B3E9E68 past requested size of 20

I don't see what I'm doing wrong...

For information here is the full definition of my class [Interpolation.h](http://pastebin.com/FMVWZwdj) and [Interpolation.cpp](http://pastebin.com/HeJAHtt4) if that's of any help.

Added a destructor but still didn't fix the problem.

```
Interpolation::~Interpolation()
{
    delete m_progress;
    m_progress = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1.  You give an excellent, brief test case.

Comment: I dont see a destructor method in your cpp file???  If you allocate memory within your object, you will most likely have to provide a custom destructor do properly destroy the object on delete!

Comment: @trumpetlicks the only object that I allocate dynamicly is m_progress but as it's a QWidget with a parent I thought the parent would take care of it. Anyway if I make a constructor for it such as `Interpolation::~Interpolation(){delete m_progress; m_progress = 0;}` I still run into the same problem.

Comment: I have the same thought @trumpetlicks has.  What can you tell us (or tell yourself) about the member initializer `m_progress(new QProgressDialog(m_parent)),` in your implementation code?  Does it not mean that your `Interpolation` class wants a destructor?  Whether this want is what causes the specific error in question, I do not know, but it wants to be fixed in any case -- so fixing it should either solve the problem or narrow the search for the problem.

Comment: @thb I did but it didn't fix the problem (see my previous answer).

Comment: @thb a 160 line constructor looks like a brief test case to you?

Comment: @trumpetlicks:  The reason the parent won't take care of it is that there is nothing in your code to tell the parent *when* to take care of it.  As you have defined it, the pointer `m_progress` dies when the `Interpolation` object dies; but the thing it points to, a `QProgressDialog` object, is left to linger, leaked, on the heap.  The concept involved here is nontrivial but essential to grasp.

Comment: What is "m_convexHull" you in your constructor call a routine called convexHull. DOes this allocate your "m_convexHull" variable???  Another thing that may not be being deleted in a destructor!

Comment: @trumpetlicks convexHull() is defined [here](http://pastebin.com/HeJAHtt4) line 311. But tmpearce found the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ctor:
Populating `m_w`: up to `(m_N-1)`

```
for (int i(0); i < m_N; ++i)
{
    m_pt.push_back(QPointF(mesureList[i]->getX(), mesureList[i]->getY()));
    m_w.push_back(mesureList[i]->getAngle());
}
```

Later: accessing `m_w[m_N]`, beyond the end of the vector

```
for (i = m_N; i >= 0; --i)
{
    sum = m_w[i];
    for (j = i+1; j < m_N; j++) sum -= LU[i][j]*m_w[j];
    m_w[i] = sum / LU[i][i];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time to find such an error, thanks anyway, this solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Something inside the constructor Interpolation::Interopolation() or the destructor Interpolation::~Interpolation() is writing beyond the size of the object.

Comment: When I comment the `delete` line I don't have any problem so I think the constructor is okay and as the destructor is empty I don't see where the problem can come from...

Comment: Specifically you do a lot of filling in fixed sized arrays in the ctor - one of those indices is wrong.

Comment: @leo - in a release build the OS doesn't check when writing to an array, it may only be after the dtor that the OS checks the stack and finds the problem

Comment: No. Writing outside the buffer may have happened in the constructor, but was detected only when the buffer was returned to the heap.

Comment: @MartinBeckket I don't see what you mean by "a lot", my only fixed size array is `QRgb m_couleurs[9];` and I fill it only once plus I've checked its indices and they're good. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Following @MartinBeckett's comment, just to make sure:  The error does not occur if you omit the `delete` statement.  Is this correct?

Comment: I cannot find your implementation of the destructor. Am I missing something? If not the compiler is generating the default constructor for you. You are allocating m_progress with new operator in the constructor, so at least, you will experience a memory leak.

Comment: @Leo you initialise a couple of fixed sized arrays with [m_N], have you checked how much you actualy copy into them?